# I have 3 different sized texts with their own images below, added height to align them but when its mobile version there's big gaps in between

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I got 3 news articles, each with its own image below. Problem is the text are quotes and varies in sizes. So they do not align, added height px which works for the Desktop version but when it goes to the mobile version the height is still obviously there and make a big weird gap between the articles.

```
<div style="padding-top:50px;" class="container">
<div class="card-deck">
<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="card" style="margin:0!important;border:none;">
<div class="card-body">
<p style="text-align:center" class="card-text">"With an impressive and evergrowing number of studies finding CBD to be a powerful antioxidant and anti-inflammatory among many other properties, it is now being used to treat pain, anxiety, spasms, and much more"</p>
</div>
<img class="card-img-top" src="img\quote_pic1.png" alt="Daily Mail" style="width:50%;height:40px;margin:auto;">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="card" style="margin:0!important;border:none;">
<div class="card-body">
<p style="text-align:center" class="card-text">“I think there is a legitimate medicine here,” he said. “We’re talking about something that could really help people.” Neurosurgeon Dr. Sanjay Gupta</p>
</div>
<img class="card-img-top" src="img\quote_pic2.png" alt="World Health Organization" style="width:50%;height:40px;margin:auto;">
</div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-4">
<div class="card" style="margin:0!important;border:none;">
<div class="card-body">
<p style="text-align:center" class="card-text">Dr. Esther Blessing, an associate professor of psychiatry at New York University says  current evidence suggests that CBD shows promise for helping to treat everything from Anxiety to PTSD</p>
</div>
<img class="card-img-top" src="img\quote_pic3.png" alt="The Washington Post" style="width:80%;height:40px;margin:auto;">
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

[Mobile Version Big Gaps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X99Tn.png)

[image: Desktop version Aligned Properly]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend removing the columns. You're in a card-deck, and you can set how many cards show per row/column in your CSS.

Additionally, I removed the `margin:0!important;border:none;` as **1)** inline isn't great, and **2)** this can be taken care of with built-in Bootstrap styles `m-0` and `border-0`. Also `text-center` removes the need for inline centering on your `<p>` tags.

Here is the result... (images added so I can see how actual images appear)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="container pt-5">
  <div class="card-deck">
    <div class="card m-0 border-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text tex-center">"With an impressive and evergrowing number of studies finding CBD to be a powerful antioxidant and anti-inflammatory among many other properties, it is now being used to treat pain, anxiety, spasms, and much more"</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/fff/000&text=LOGO" style="max-width: 40%;" alt="Daily Mail">
    </div>

    <div class="card m-0 border-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text tex-center">“I think there is a legitimate medicine here,” he said. “We’re talking about something that could really help people.” Neurosurgeon Dr. Sanjay Gupta</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/fff/000&text=LOGO" style="max-width: 40%;" alt="World Health Organization">
    </div>

    <div class="card m-0 border-0">
      <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text tex-center">Dr. Esther Blessing, an associate professor of psychiatry at New York University says current evidence suggests that CBD shows promise for helping to treat everything from Anxiety to PTSD</p>
      </div>
      <img class="card-img-top mx-auto" src="https://dummyimage.com/100x50/fff/000&text=LOGO" style="max-width: 40%;" alt="The Washington Post">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much webfrogs!

Comment: @OMGIt'sJasonBornToCode - Anytime! (btw - love that username)